# how does the initialization A(ob) work, where ob is an object of class A

Tags: c++, class, object

A is a class defined like this:

```
class A
{
  public:
     int x; 
}
```

And main:

```
int main()
{
   A(ob);    // note that copy constructor doesn't get called
   ob.x = 1; // just to show that ob's members can be accessed
}
```

Here's a different main():

```
int main()
{
  A ob;
  A ob2 = A(ob); // copy constructor gets called and everything happens as expected
}
```

I've never seen an instantiation like this in c++. Isn't A(ob) supposed to be function style type casting by calling A's constructor where `ob` was a previously declared object?

EDIT: In the second main(), A(ob) is used as an initializer for `ob2`.

Comment: @Kal There is no copy to elide. What would you be copying from? You have just default constructed an `A` called `ob`.

Comment: @juanchopanza ya i didn't kno it was same as `A ob`, thought it was copying from `ob` into temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A(ob);
```

is same as:

```
A ob;
```

The braces are superfluous. So the following are same as above:

```
A((ob)); 
A(((ob))); 
A((((ob))));
```

All are equivalent.  But that doesn't mean you should write this. Just write what is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Strange as it may seem

```
A(ob);
```

is equivalent to

```
A ob;
```

in your code.

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought. A(ob) works differently when ob is defined before and you initialize another object with it.